# Secure testing config profile still affects me after deletion?

Tags: configuration-profiles

Recently installed a secure browser profile for state testing onto my Mac (Running Catalina 10.15.7), which does annoying things like not allowing screenshots or desktop swapping. After I was finished with it, I tried to delete the config profile with `/usr/bin/profiles -D` and I did get the prompt to delete all config profiles. Afterwards, running `/usr/bin/profiles -L` returned `There are no configuration profiles installed for user 'aaronshih'`. However, I still cannot screenshot or swap desktops. I tried installing a new configuration profile from Apple Configurator that had the default permissions with everything enabled, but that also didn't do anything. How can I actually undo the effects of an already deleted config profile?

Comment: Have you relogged/rebooted?

Comment: Does the profile appear in System Preferences- Profiles? Remove it via the GUI. The command line access to profiles doesn’t work well with newer macOS versions.

Comment: @JamesBrickley yeah, I fixed it now. The issue was that even after removing the profile, I had to manually reset my settings through the GUI.